# Keras cnn model, doesnt give even average accuracy

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am training a model which consists of signal data and is multi dimensional.

I processed the data and it contains 179 samples.

```
The following is the shape of the data.
f1 = f1.reshape((179, 15, 1, 5120))
f2 = f2.reshape((179, 15, 1, 5120))
f3 = f3.reshape((179, 15, 1, 5120))
```

which are features, and below are labels.

```
# One hot encoding, multi classification
l1 = np_utils.to_categorical(l1)
l2 = np_utils.to_categorical(l2)
l3 = np_utils.to_categorical(l3)
```

so the shape of my features and labels is:

```
(179, 15, 1, 5120)
(179, 15, 1, 5120)
(179, 15, 1, 5120)
(179, 3)
(179, 3)
(179, 3)
```

I am using the following architecture of keras CNN model

```
from sklearn.metrics import cohen_kappa_score, make_scorer
kappa_scorer = make_scorer(cohen_kappa_score)

sgd = SGD(lr = 0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.5, nesterov=True)
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 1), border_mode="same", input_shape=(15, 1, 5120), kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(1,1)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(64))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))    
    model.add(Dense(32))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation="softmax"))
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Now, I train my model,

```
# Fit the model
model.fit(f3, l3, epochs=200, batch_size=5)
```

here is the outcome.
And it keep going like this, the data is all numerical. 
I want to optimise my model. Dont know how to proceed.

```
Epoch 1/200
179/179 [==============================] - 9s 50ms/step - loss: 9.6746 - acc: 0.3799
Epoch 2/200
179/179 [==============================] - 8s 43ms/step - loss: 10.1751 - acc: 0.3687
Epoch 3/200
179/179 [==============================] - 8s 43ms/step - loss: 10.1751 - acc: 0.3687
Epoch 4/200
179/179 [==============================] - 8s 47ms/step - loss: 10.1751 - acc: 0.3687
Epoch 5/200
179/179 [==============================] - 9s 48ms/step - loss: 10.1751 - acc: 0.3687
```

Comment: if you got signal data, why are you transforming to canonical data? And why did you define kappa_scorer and sgd if you didn't use them?

Comment: I dont about the transformation, you are saying, another thing,I was using kappa scorer in grid search and sgd as well with adam to see how it affects accurcacy. i made predictions with model and it all predicted one class and kappa value was zero.